# Value of variable in dictionary changed in python

Tags: python

```
cA1 = 1
cA2 = 0

dict_1 = {1: cA1, 2:cA2}

q=2

dict_1[q] = [3,6,9]

print dict_1[q]
print cA2
```

I'm stuck in the question why variable `cA2` is different form the variable in `dict_1[q]` when both of them are referring to `cA2`. As the output for `dict_1[q]` is `[3,6,9]` but `0` for `cA2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the value in the dictionary, you're overwriting the reference of the previous value, so there's no way you can get to `cA2` this way. One more hindrance is that integers are *immutable*, so there's no way to change the value of `cA2` as it is defined.

One way would be:

- define `cA2` as a `list`
- assign it using *slice notation* (`[:]`)

like this:

```
cA1 = 1
cA2 = []

dict_1 = {1: cA1, 2:cA2}

q=2

dict_1[q][:] = [3,6,9]  # assign using slice: change value not reference

print(dict_1[q])
print(cA2)
```

Now `cA2` is updated, and both values are now equal:

```
[3, 6, 9]
[3, 6, 9]
```